# Second order differential equation resolution.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving the following Cauchy problem

\begin{cases} y''(t) = \frac{-4y'(t)}{y(t)^2} \\y(0) = 2 \\ y'(0) = 2 \end{cases}

By setting $v(s) = u'(u^{-1}(s))$ where $u \in C^1(I,R)$ is a solution to the starting differential equation.

I then obtain the problem

\begin{cases} v'(s) = \frac{-4}{s^2} \\v(2) = 2  \end{cases}

that is equivalent to $$\int_2^s v'( \sigma) d \sigma = \int_2^s -4/ \sigma^2 d\sigma$$

this gives me $v(s) = 4/s$

So in order to get a solution to the original problem I now must solve

\begin{cases} y'(t) = \frac{-4}{t} \\y(0) = 2  \end{cases}

but I must of made an error during my resolution because $\log(0)$ is not defined (it comes out of solving this).

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The derivative of $1/y$ is $-y'/y^2$ hence $y''=-4y'/y^2$ implies $y'=4/y+C$. Since $y'(0)=y(0)=2$, $C=0$ and $2y'y=8$, which can be integrated as $y^2=8t+c$. The initial condition $y(0)=2$ yields $c=4$. Finally, $y>0$ hence $y(t)=2\sqrt{2t+1}$ for every $t>-\frac12$.

Comment: You might have gone wrong when using $\nu(s)=4/s$ to deduce $y'(t)=4/t$ instead of $y'(t)=4/y(t)$. (Not that the procedure you seem to apply would be necessary in any way in the present case...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''(t)=4\left(\dfrac1{y(t)}\right)',$$
$$y'(t)=\dfrac4{y(t)}+C.$$
If $t=0,$ then $2=\dfrac42+C,\quad C=0$, so
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac4y,$$
$$2ydy=8dt,$$
$$y^2=8t+C.$$
If $t=0,$ then $4=C,$ so
$$y^2=8t+4,$$
$$\boxed{y=\pm\sqrt{8t+4}}$$